# Parallel.Foreach is overriding the System.IO.File operation & causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have a windows service code in C#.NET and it looking like this below one. I am trying to write the pdf in parallel.foreach in the large files array of 10,000 or 50,000 files. MaxDegreeOfParallelism is set to 10 , so that files can be created concurrently or parallel in a faster way.

But i am receiving the **error on the line File.WriteAllBytes** saying **The process cannot access the file 'Hello.pdf' because it is being used by another process.**

The data inside the files array is unique. File names are unique in the entire array set.

I feel Parallel.Foreach is creating multiple thread but its not atomic on the files array data.

Please suggest how to fix this issue or let me know how to use Parallel.Foreach in a better way.

```
 ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
 po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
        Parallel.ForEach(files, po, newpath =>
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(newpath);
                File.WriteAllBytes(newpath.ToString().Replace(sourcePath, destinationPath), bytes);
                Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceLog.WriteTrace("Failed copy this file: " + newpath.ToString() + " " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Comment: it is random and causing the issue sometimes only

Comment: What's content of `files`? Does it contain duplicate `filepath`?

Comment: There is no duplicate in the files array. I checked it also.

Comment: Could you please enrich your code with some sample values, e. g. for `newpath` and `destinationPath`? Are you always reading the same file with `File.ReadAllBytes()`?

Comment: Not really related, but why are you calling `Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`? It's pointless. Also `Interlocked.Increment(ref count);` - what's that for?

Comment: I assume that you're accessing the same 'Hello.pdf' twice. Try to apply Linq `.Distinct()` to your files array, before execution. Like this - `Parallel.ForEach(files, po, newpath => ...`

Comment: In any case, this whole thing is kind of pointless - there's not much advantage to be had by trying to copy 10 files simultaneously - it will block on I/O anyway, and it's entirely likely that trying to parallelise I/O like this will actually make things *slower*!

Comment: Hello.pdf is just an example for the post. In my case, the file name is longer one and is unique. You are right, i am using Interlocked.Increment on count variable for later use to check the impacted files in the tracelog

Comment: I hope you are trying to write to the same destination path in all the parallel threads. Can you share us on how sourcepath and destination path being generated or check or trace on the destination path being used for file.writeallbytes?

Comment: Since i am doing File.WriteAllBytes inside the Parallel.Foreach and that could be problem. Parallel.Foreach is meant for CPU based work not I/O based work.